# MATLAB: Cannot read AVI file in new version

Tags: windows, matlab, video, codec

MATLAB has deprecated `mmreader` and `aviread` in favour of their new `VideoReader` function to read video files. However, according to their [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html), it cannot read avi files on Windows 7 or later, so on my R2015b installation on Windows 10, I am left with *no* way to read an avi file (`aviread` and `mmreader` have been removed). `VideoReader` throws the following error:

```
>> VideoReader('test5a.avi')
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Unable to determine the codec required.

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);
```

Any ideas to read an avi file then?

Comment: Is the required Codec installed? http://superuser.com/questions/23512/how-do-i-find-the-codec-for-an-avi

Comment: VideoReader can be used to read AVI files. I do not believe the documentation says otherwise. AVI is a container and the video data it contains can be encoded using a codec that is not present on your system? Are you able to open the file using Windows Media Player?